# SSRS 2012 Subreport export to excel for only current months

Tags: excel, reporting-services, export-to-excel, subreport

I have a report which contains subreports for each month of the year. I set them up so each month is on new sheet with its name.

Do you know how to set that only completed months appears? 
I mean for January 2016 I want to see only sheet January ´16. Now I see all 12 months.

Thank you,

Petra

Comment: You have to provide more details here. How do you fetch the data? Mdx, Sql etc.

Comment: Both MDX and SQL, I´m having datasets which are written with MDX from cube and also few datasets written in SQL.
I added empty matrix between the subreports to add a break and set PageName.